# How can i increase height of CollectionView indexTitles?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

**Reference view**

[image: image link1]

I am trying to show collection view indexTitle according to the screen height.

I want to show collection view IndexTitle according to this view.

[image: image link2]

Comment: I think for to do that you need third party library.

Comment: There is no API for changing the section index view. You would need to write your own replacement. You may be able to find some examples / 3rd-party options out there that you could use as a starting point if you don't find one that's right for your needs.

Comment: can you please suggest any 3rd party library for collection view index title?